# Error Code 0x0 when upgrading from Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Professional

Tags: operating-system, windows-10

Error in upgrading my Windows10 home to Windows10 pro. This is the error below:

Error Code 0x0 when upgrading from Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Professional

Comment: I also encountered this error, you may try to uninstall the anti-virus maybe that will works.

Comment: I already uninstalled my antivirus but I have the same error. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention the procedure you followed for upgrading.
Anyways in short if you have a valid License key purchased for Pro, just call micro soft support [go to -https://support.microsoft.com/en-in , then search for Activation/Update select option to get call] they will get it done in 10-15 mnts.

This is the over all Process you have to follow while being on call with them-
Actually support agent will give you one default upgrade key
1. Go to This Comp >Properties > Change product key enter the product key and turn off ur internet/wifi before hitting next, 
2. this will upgrade your home to Pro after one restart and installations.
3. Once done turn on wifi
4. you will now see window's version changed to Pro but its not activated under My Comp Properties
5.Now again click change product Key> Enter the Activation key you've purchased and you'll be done in few seconds if this is a genuine key..
that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Download Windows 10 Professional then perform a repair upgrade:

How to download official Windows 10 ISO files

then

How to: perform a repair upgrade using the Windows 10 ISO file